# Ubuntu won't use a drive until I open it in Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin

I store all my wallpapers on a separate hard drive from the OS. After booting, the wallpapers won't display until I open Dolphin and click on the drive. Is there a way to correct that behavior?

Thanks!

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-72-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NV167

Comment: `System Settings` > `Removable Storage` gives you the options to automount drives. If you need it more detailed, please tell us which version of Kubuntu you use.

Comment: as @mook765 stated. The manual method is to add it to `/etc/fstab` and add a line for it

Comment: Which supported Ubuntu release are you using? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting